# Count Letters in String without Spacebar

Tags: c#, c++, c, string, counter

I wanna count the length of the string (including spaces) with the function `strlen()` and the length of the string without the spaces. The former works, but I have problems with the latter.

Example:

```
Hello User//including spaces:10 letters//without spaces:9
```

When I enter a word without spaces the program always count:100, when with 1 space: I get 99 and so on.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define N 100

int main()
{
    int counter1 = 0, i;
    char string1[N] = {0};
    {
        gets(string1);
        printf("\nYour Text:\n%s",string1);
        printf("\nLength of String:%i Letters(with spaces)", strlen(string1));
        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            if(string1[i] != ' ' && string1[i] != '0')
                counter1++;
        }
        printf("Number of Letters(without spaces): %i",counter1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `C`, `C++`, `C#`: pick one. Also, your `if` condition is incorrect.

Comment: The for loop doesnt have to go untill N, just to strlen(string1)

Comment: gets does not have boundary check, use fgets instead of gets.

Comment: condition like this `if(string1[i]!=' ' && string1[i]!='\0')`

Comment: Note that spacebar is a keyboard key, the character it produces is just called a space.

Comment: @unwind sorry, i am german :D

Comment: @pmg what can i use instead of gets? scanf in a loop?

Comment: @user3336852 use `fgets()` to read a complete line, then, if needed, remove the newline to get the same functionality as `gets()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(str[i]!='\0')
 {
     if(str[i]!=' ')
     {
         count++;
     }
     i++;
 }
```

this loop works or chnage your for loop to

```
for(i=0; i<strlen(string1); i++)
        {
            if(string1[i] != ' ' && string1[i] != '0')
                counter1++;
        }
```

since you used

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
```

where `N=100` and c will not check for out of bound access therefore the loop continues till `i=100` this resulted in `count=100-number of spaces`.

Answer (score 4):

You have not considered that the string terminate with '\n'. Your code will run from 0 till 100 so you will always get 100 as result. You could change your code with something like this:

```
i=0;
while(string1[i]!='\n' && string1[i]!='\0')
{
  if(string1[i]!=' ') {
      counter1++;
  }

  i++;
}
```

Please take note that in C the default string therminator character is '\0' and not 0

Comment: Code doesn't compile.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i have changed the code so now it should compile without errors

Comment: this code works, i doenst have to add \n to the loop.    for(i=0;i<strlen(string1);i++)
        {
          if(string1[i]!=' '&&string1[i]!='\0')
            counter1++;
        }

Comment: @user3336852 the solution i posted is only one. You could find more than one (give a look at the other answers)

Answer (score 3):

if you want a C++ answer (you did add C++ tag), then you can do :

```
std::string tmp(str);
int cpt = std::count_if(tmp.begin(),tmp.end(),[](char c){return c != ' ';});
```

Answer (score 2):

In C#:

```
int numberOfChars = yourString != null ? yourString.Replace(" ", "").Count() : 0;
```

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Comment: This fails if `yourString` is `NULL`.

Comment: I assumed it was checked and that the point of the question was another one... Anyway here's the improved solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must check for NULL (string1[i] == 0) character. Once you encounter NULL, break from the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

my approach would be:

```
int len = strlen(string1);
int lenWithoutSpace = len;
for(int i=0; i<len; ++len){
  if(string1[i]==' '){
    lenWithoutSpace--;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
int main()
{
int counter1=0,i;
char string1[N]={0};
{   
gets(string1);
printf("\nYour Text:\n%s",string1);
printf("\nLength of String:%i Letters(with spacebar)",strlen(string1));
 for(i=0;i<strlen(string1);i++)
{
  if(string1[i]!=' '&&string1[i]!='0')
    counter1++;
}    
printf("Number of Letters(without spacebar): %i",counter1);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop adds up to 100, excluding the space and '0', which i believe you want it to be '\0'. Change the loop to 0 to strlen(string1) and the if condition, and it should work fine. Although there can be better ways.